# Making a Matrix element equals the row number times the column number in matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, matrix-multiplication, multiplication

I want to declare a function that takes (n, m) as inputs an return mt as a n-by-m matrix. and if I assume that the row number (rn) and the column number (cn)
I want a given element of mt matrix = row number(rn)*column number(cn)

```
function  [mt, s] = mtable(n, m)
mt = rand(n, m);
rn = (1:n);
cn = (1:m);
mt(rn, cn) = rn*cn;
s = sum(mt);
end
```

Comment: This question has been asked many times.  The duplicate link that I referenced is the most recent time.  In the future please consider doing a search to see if your question exists before actually posting a question.  It will minimize clutter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can simply do

```
mt = [1:n].'*[1:m]
```

to achieve the matrix you desire. Otherwise, you have some syntax issues in the example code you posted.

Comment: The difference will be almost imperceptible, but using circular backets instead of square brackets is more efficient, and you don't need the dot in the transpose: (1:n)'*(1:n).

Answer (score 2):

You can directly calculate `s` with simple scaling of `cn` with with the total sum of `rn` and thus without being bothered by `mt` like so -

```
function s = mtable(n, m)
rn = (1:n);
cn = (1:m);
s = cn*sum(rn)
end
```

If you *really* need mt as well, you can use [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) -

```
mt = bsxfun(@times,rn',cn)
```